# Including "and" word as a separator in ToWords function

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2010

I am using the ToWords function in Crystal Report to convert figures to words. The amounts may sometimes contain decimal values as well, therefore I have included an IF condition to evaluate it include the decimals section only when necessary.

However I also need to add a "and" words to separate the amount in words so that it is easier to read.

For Eg. 38426 should be displayed as "Thirty eight thousand two hundred and forty six". At the moment this reads as "Thirty eight thousand two hundred forty six".

Here is the code that I have in place at the moment.

```
    NUMBERVAR amount    := 38246;
    NUMBERVAR decimals  := (Round(amount,2) - Int(amount)) * 100;
    STRINGVAR words     := 'Rupees';

    words := words & ' ' & TOWORDS(amount,0);

    IF(decimals > 0) THEN words := words & ' and ' &TOWORDS(decimals,0) & ' cents';

    words := PROPERCASE(words & ' only');
```

Comment: are you trying to add `and` to before `tens` place?

Comment: No it should work for figures like 130000, which would read One hundred and thirteen thousand only. It would be great if it could work to any number regardless of the amount. Is this possible ??

Comment: For any unit (hundreds, thousands, millions, etc.) can't you just check to see if the hundred's and ten's place of that unit are non-zero and add an 'and' between them if so?. So in your example, the hundred's (1) place and ten's place (30) of thousands unit are non-zero so you would add an 'and': one hundred AND thirty thousand

Comment: [This posting](http://budgeting.thenest.com/correct-way-spell-out-dollar-amounts-23624.html) suggests that you only need to add an 'and' if the numerical value contains a decimal value.  So, $1100 is 'one thousand, one hundred Dollars', while $100.10 is 'one hundred Dollars and ten Cents'.  If it isn't a currency, I would tend to hyphenate and use commas: '55,123.35 = 'fifty-five thousand, one hundred, twenty three POINT three five.

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom function:

```
//Wordy()
Function (Numbervar Value)

If Remainder(Value,1)=0 Then
    ProperCase(ToWords(Value,0)) + " Dollars"
Else
    Replace(Replace(ProperCase(ToWords(Value,2)), "And", "Dollars And"), "/ 100", "Cents")
```

Use function in a formula field:

```
// Fifty-Five Thousand One Hundred Twenty-Three Dollars
Wordy(55123.00)

// Fifty-Five Thousand One Hundred Twenty-Three Dollars And 55 Cents
Wordy(55123.55)
```

Comment: Your custom function looks neat, thanks.. But unfortunately I can't seem to use it, VS crashes when I try to use this function & click on save on the formula window. :( .. 

Anyways I need `Wordy(55123.00)` to be displayed as Fifty-Five thousand one hundred and twenty three. Not as Fifty-Five Thousand One Hundred Twenty-Three which I already get by default

Answer (score 0):

It is tricky yet simple...
1. Convert 38426 to display in default format of the towords function.
this is rendered as "thirty eight thousand four hundred twenty six"
2. Put this default result in a variable say "txt"
3. Use internal function "Replace" to search for the word "Hundred" and replace it with "Hundred and". This solves the problem.

In actual detail...

```
currencyvar tt; 
currencyvar dect; 
stringvar txt;
tt := 38426 ; 
dect := tt - Truncate(tt); 
tt := truncate(tt); 
dect := dect * 100; 
if dect = 0 then //default format 

ProperCase (ToWords (tt,0 ) + ' Dollars Only' ) // without decimal (cents)
else 

txt := ProperCase (ToWords (tt,0) + ' Dollars, ' + ToWords(dect,0) + ' cents Only'); 

//include "and"
Replace (txt,"Hundred" ,"Hundred and" )
```

Edit:
the above is an improvement on the solution found here
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/thread/235835/number-to-words-in-crystal-report.aspx